# Background image not displaying. Css problems

Tags: css

I am trying to figure out why I can't see the image.
I am trying to add an image in the `<li class="logo"><a href="indexS.html">PufferFish Divers</a></li>`  line, but I just see a black space.
When I inspect it, it is there, but I cannot get to see it.

```
header .logo a {
  background-image: url("https://www.dropbox.com/s/ie6qd07mbmonjs1/sea10%20copia.jpeg?dl=0") ;
  background-size: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 80px;
  width: 300px;
  text-indent: -999999999px;
}
```

Here's a [codepen link](https://codepen.io/wulfo/pen/yLMdvLG).

Comment: sorry, not trying to do so. I posted a codepen Link with all the code just above.
I was having problems attaching a snippet here....all time getting the "it looks that there is only code " error message, despite all the additional information and description included

Comment: The image link inside css does not return an image file, it returns a web page, have you checked adding another image just for testing?

Comment: This is the actual link to the image you inserted: https://uccf62af6085e46bfa876477ddd6.previews.dropboxusercontent.com/p/thumb/ABP0IK4DkxiZRD-oqNgvuM_MQx2MKut92ZE3MOLBMM2_aHYJ1Oz_fFc8c8B-zQ0R6PWpG8SlVUKL-hDW8HukOeP_nXbuZvH1XDQpMMEpDEFZgc7He81YmTuC1hE1V953GsqDwB9mZoR22b1VrWVxf0gmDyU8wv1x05cMbY8JDDqayTLMS0-S0_3mf7ELwNXB-FEacQjlV3KmTw82mpj1rx_N-rN9V4gT7-284Zo-A3_cBQ0ursYlyJ563tPMvzed852kpQJ5vp9Dwpf1mkEh1_xZAizECUuPvDZGc39xweogbwP_2blHPFW6wsu1xoffpb7Z3PPNz4tb2-EEcgJaT3SdfFVjHzXSoB0e4hF3Dy9dpbNcdTzmhDVp5rt6YKtbMCqBP2WNepm_EVDWH_VH4kW5/p.jpeg?size=1600x1200&size_mode=3

Comment: hey @decoder , thanks for your reply. 
Yeah, I tried with .jpg and .png pictures too. I just uploaded one to dropbox to attach it to the snippet as an example.

Comment: I found the issue. It was as simple as a problem with the image´s path  I-) 
Thanks a lot for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

here is  the code. you can try this out. and you can refer [enter link description here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp) here for more details.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
body  {
  background-image: url("https://uccf62af6085e46bfa876477ddd6.previews.dropboxusercontent.com/p/thumb/ABP0IK4DkxiZRD-oqNgvuM_MQx2MKut92ZE3MOLBMM2_aHYJ1Oz_fFc8c8B-zQ0R6PWpG8SlVUKL-hDW8HukOeP_nXbuZvH1XDQpMMEpDEFZgc7He81YmTuC1hE1V953GsqDwB9mZoR22b1VrWVxf0gmDyU8wv1x05cMbY8JDDqayTLMS0-S0_3mf7ELwNXB-FEacQjlV3KmTw82mpj1rx_N-rN9V4gT7-284Zo-A3_cBQ0ursYlyJ563tPMvzed852kpQJ5vp9Dwpf1mkEh1_xZAizECUuPvDZGc39xweogbwP_2blHPFW6wsu1xoffpb7Z3PPNz4tb2-EEcgJaT3SdfFVjHzXSoB0e4hF3Dy9dpbNcdTzmhDVp5rt6YKtbMCqBP2WNepm_EVDWH_VH4kW5/p.jpeg?fv_content=true&size_mode=5");
  background-color: #cccccc;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 300px 100px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>The background-image Property</h1>

<p>Hello World!</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is mistake in the image's url. It was just a letter, but made it impossible to reach.